# How do fix a broken PPA which pertains to installing Ethereum?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, 19.10, ethereum

https://linuxconfig.org/ethereum-mining-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-debian is old link
I did type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
```

then

```
sudo apt update
```

but when I type

```
sudo apt install ethereum
```

I get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ethereum
```

How can this be fixed!

It's was better to install Bitcoin Core 0.18.1 on Raspbian than trying Ethereum on Ubuntu 19.10!  The 256GB is not enough to download the Bitcoin blockchain.  I might have to go to 512GB if I had the chance for Bitcoin!

I did try typing

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
```

but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [the build failed](https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+packages#pub10586806-container) for amd64 and i386 on 19.10 eoan.

However, it also looks like [there is no arm build available through this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+sourcepub/10586806/+listing-archive-extra). This ppa only provides i386 and amd64 packages.

Comment: Well if there's no PPA (Personal Package Archive) on arm64 for ethereum, then it's time to build one!  If you have access to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas there's a treasure full of PPA for arm64! I hope I can gain more experience with from going from Raspian September 2019 to Ubuntu 19.10! I was able to pull an all nighter to install  Ubuntu 19.10 on a SanDisk Extreme 64GB microSDXC! @mchid

Comment: @RedalioEOcampo If you go to the first link in my answer and click on the expansion arrow for the ethereum package for eoan you will see the source package listed. Here is the link: https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+sourcefiles/ethereum/1.9.6+build20165+eoan/ethereum_1.9.6+build20165+eoan.tar.xz but it looks like it is on wait for a dependency: https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+build/17839971.